# Oracle SELECT FOR UPDATE on a single row with ORDER BY: ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I have a control table and want to be able to select for update a single row in this control table.

However, using an `ORDER BY` and `WHERE rownum = 1` along with a `FOR UPDATE` results in `ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc`.

This is possible in Postgresql. Is there a way to accomplish this in Oracle?

## Set up

```
drop table foo;

create table foo (
    bar int, 
    last_update_date date
);

insert into foo (
    bar, 
    last_update_date
) select level, 
    null
from dual 
connect by level <= 10;

commit;
```

## Issue

The following `FOR UPDATE` with the `ORDER BY` fails with `ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.`:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from foo
    where last_update_date is null
    order by bar
)
where rownum = 1
for update skip locked;
```

Removing the `ORDER BY` works, but is not the behavior that I want.

## Workaround

The workaround that I have is to select all rows into memory:

```
select *
from foo
where last_update_date is null
order by bar
for update;
```

Followed by an update to the first row in the result set and a commit.

This is not that great. Not only does it not scale but it also blocks concurrent threads for much longer than it would if I could just select for update a single row.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from foo
where last_update_date is null
order by bar
for update;
```

Will only lock the rows that get fetched. Have your calling code just fetch a single result and you will only be locking a single row at a time. If you are using PL/SQL for your processing, this means just using the

```
Open cursor
Fetch cursor into resultVariables
Do processing
Commit
Close cursor
```

You could be better off looking into Advanced Queueing (dbms_aq) which handles a lot of this for you.